# Mount point attribution

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, go, mount

I'm reading the source code of docker,and it checks if one directory has been mounted by such a test condition,what's the principle behind it?

```
func Mounted(mountpoint string) (bool, error) {
    mntpoint, err := os.Stat(mountpoint)
    if err != nil {
        if os.IsNotExist(err) {
                return false, nil
        }
        return false, err
    }
    parent, err := os.Stat(filepath.Join(mountpoint, ".."))
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
    mntpointSt := mntpoint.Sys().(*syscall.Stat_t)
    parentSt := parent.Sys().(*syscall.Stat_t)
    return mntpointSt.Dev != parentSt.Dev, nil
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `stat(2)` man page on Linux:

> The `st_dev` field describes the device on which this file resides.  (The `major(3)` and  `minor(3)` macros may be useful to decompose the device ID in this field.)

So what the code in question is doing is invoking the `stat` system call on the directory and its parent and checking whether they reside on different devices.  This can only be true if they are on different file systems, which would indicate that the directory in question is a mount point.

Comment: you mean that each mounted directory has different st_dev or only the directory which is mounted and it's parent on different st_dev?

Comment: Every file or directory you call `stat` on will have the `st_dev` field set to tell you which device it belongs to.  The point is that if two files/directories have different `st_dev` values, then they belong to different devices.  As a corollary, if a directory belongs to a different device than its parent directory then it must be a mount point.